# jquery animate font-size for all children

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, children

To be specified
Well let's have this lines of code:

```
<style type="text/css">
a{
font-size:20px;
}
</style>
<div id="an" style="font-size:14px">
    <a style="font-size:12px;">Bla bla bla</a>
    <p style="font-size:10px;">Bla bla bla</p>
    <a href="#">Bla bla bla</a>
    <!-- what ever goes here-->
</div>
```

i want to make a function which  will simultaneously use .animate() method of jquery library
to animate the font-size of all child elements and the font-size of the parent element (#an) to 1.2*current_font_size

To be more understandable i write the use of the function to the above code

```
<style type="text/css">
a{
font-size:20px;
}
</style>
<div id="an" style="font-size:1.2*14px">
    <a style="font-size:1.2*12px;">Bla bla bla</a>
    <p style="font-size:1.2*10px;">Bla bla bla</p>
    <a style="font-size:1.2*20px" href="#">Bla bla bla</a>
    <!-- what ever goes here-->
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is your JavaScript code?  Typically, you would not come here and expect us to write your entire function from scratch.  If you don't have anything written yet, [this is a good starting point](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: i want to make it but i don't know how..
I know to do the following but i don't want to do this!
new_size=1.2*parseFloat($("#an").css('font-size'));
$("#an").animate({fontSize: new_size+"px"},400);

Comment: Sorry Chris... Stackoverflow is for programming questions...   if you get stuck writing a function, people here are willing to help.  Most are not willing to write entire functions from scratch for free.  You have to start someplace... [http://www.impressivewebs.com/jquery-tutorial-for-beginners/](http://www.impressivewebs.com/jquery-tutorial-for-beginners/).  BTW, **why** don't you want to do that?  It's JavaScript/jQuery which is what you asked us to do for you!

Comment: Because this will animate only the parent font-size
If any child (as the example) has inline css code for font-size this will not change..

Comment: Chris, the JS code you quoted and your last comment should have been included in your original question!  That's my whole point.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#an, #an > *").animate({
    fontSize: 1.2*parseFloat($("#an").css('font-size'))+"px"
 },400);
```

Comment: thx gion..
This solution do exactly what I want..
Last question..
Do you have any link for $() selector?
I mean i want to learn more about #an > * or whatever you can do with this method..
Thx a lot again!

Comment: well jquery relies on css selectors to match dom nodes, so you can start at the css core : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/, or you can read the jquery documentation on selectors : http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. Note that you can combine most of the selectors to construct a query that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code.

```
<div id="an">
    <a style="font-size:12px;">Bla bla bla</a>
    <p style="font-size:10px;">Bla bla bla</p>
    <a style="font-size:20px" href="#">Bla bla bla</a>
    <!-- what ever goes here-->
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    $("#an").children().each(function(){
        fontSizeValue = parseInt($(this).css('font-size'))*1.2;
        $(this).animate({fontSize:fontSizeValue +"px"});
    })
});
</script>
```

Demo: http://www.balam.in/personal/jquery-examples/animate-font.html